# splprep and splrep returning different results for the same data in scipy

Tags: python, scipy, spline

I am trying to fit a spline through some data point and I am getting a different spline if I use `splprep` or `splrep` with the same conditions and data. `splrep` results are much easier to use, but `splprep` return the result I think is better for my data. I can't tell why. I also tried using `make_interp_spline`, but the results are the same as `splrep`.
I want the points I give to be the peaks of the spline, and for the function to interpolate between them, like `splprep` does

I am not sure what is causing the discrepancy?

```
x_points = [ 0,  5,  10, 15,  20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
y_points = [12, 5,  19,  5,  19, 5,  19, 5 ,12]
```

```
def get_spline_points(xs, ys):
    mytck,myu=itp.splprep([xs, ys], k=2, s=0)
    print(myu)
    xnew,ynew= itp.splev(np.linspace(0, 1, 1000), mytck)
    return (xnew, ynew)
```

[image: splprep output]

```
def get_spline_points(xs, ys):
    mytck=itp.splrep(x=xs, y=ys, k=2, s=0)
    ys = itp.splev(np.arange(0, 60.5, 0.5), mytck)
    return ys
```

```
def get_spline_points(xs, ys):
    bspline = interpolate.make_interp_spline(xs, ys, k=2)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    xs_n = np.arange(0, 60.5, 0.5)
    ys_n = bspline(xs_n)
    ax.plot(xs_n, ys_n, linewidth=2.0)
    ax.scatter(x_points, y_points, c='green')
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible reason is that splprep comes up with some parametrization of the curve (your myu variable). Changing parametrization changes the curve, sometimes in rather drastic ways. See e.g. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/interpolate/1D.html#parametric-spline-curves for (a rather extreme) example.

EDIT. If you want to enforce that extrema of the spline are at data points, you might want to use pchip or Akima monotone splines. These are only once continuously differentiable, but are guaranteed to not overshoot. See the scipy tutorial for an example usage.

Comment: Thanks. pchip or Akima are just what I needed. They also look exactly like `splprep` in this case, but will also be more robust for future data. Appreciate the help!